# Archive file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, categories, archive

Can anyone tell the exact use of archive.php file in wordpress. 
I've googled and got a solution as the order of templates in https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates. I wish to get a more precise answer.
Also, what will happen if I delete this file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are building a WordPress Theme, you have the option of adding a file named archive.php to your theme.

It is optional because if you don’t have it, then the index.php will handle the output of archive type posts.

Now as a refresher, an archive page in WordPress is referring to a collection of posts grouped by category, author, date, tag, etc.

Comment: Could you please tell what author.php is? Is it a type of archive file?

Comment: its use for the default template used to display author archive pages in WordPress. :-)

Comment: Could you please explain what "author archive page" is? Does those are the posts with draft status?

Comment: it will return all posts written by author. this would be a step up from relying just on the archive.php file likewise.

Additionally: Uou can build specific author.php files for individual author’s by using their author ID or nicename.
You may want all the guest authors’ information to display with author.php
you can make single template for single author too.
inshort author.php have the same function like archive.php but additinaly you can display author info.

Comment: is there anything else that i can assist you !

Comment: I am creating a documentation about wordpress. I'll ask you if any doubts arrive. Thank you

Comment: Could you please tell add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
   'aside',
   'gallery',
   'link',
   'image',
   'quote',
   'status',
   'video',
   'audio',
   'chat'
  ) );

what aside stands for?

Comment: its used to register support for certain theme features in WordPress.
For example: add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) );

allow post-thumbnails to ONLY POSTS